# link each button to new viewcontroller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, viewcontroller

i have looked for this all over the internet but i didn't find any information about this, i allowed users in my app to create buttons in scroll view, i want now to link every button to a new view created programmatically, it will have all the objects of an existing view, but i want it to be unique for this button, just like iOS notes app, every button leads to a note different from the other.
this is the button code:

```
@IBAction func add(sender: AnyObject) {
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "New Habit", message: "Please input a habit", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel) { (_) in }
    alertController.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Email"
        "\(textField.text)"
             let confirmAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .Default) { (_) in


if (textField.text=="")
                {}
                else {self.x++}
                print("\(self.x)")

        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0+CGFloat(self.x*100), -10, 100, 50)
    button.tag = Int(self.x)
    self.scroll.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(120*self.x),00)
    button.setTitle("\(textField.text!)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.whiteColor(), forState: .Normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    print("\(button.tag)")

    self.scroll.addSubview(button)
    self.collectionOfButtons?.append(button)
        }
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{        print("\(sender.tag)")

}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: sorry for not being clear, i want to create a viewcontroller linked to each new button created by user  and i want it to be like the original viewcontroller

Comment: Still not a question. What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Why create a completely new view?  Why not have a view that if it is a new button displays itself as empty?

Comment: i don't want empty view, i want the button to segue to a new view which is identical to view controller